# Generate PPT from Json file through VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

i want to convert the below Json to Power point through VBA

```json
{
  "title": "Executive Summary & Key Findings",
  "subtitle": "Executive Summary & Key Findings",
  "type": "executive_summary",
  "section_id": "",
  "template": "executive_summary",
  "meta": {
    "type": "executive_summary",
    "template": "executive_summary",
    "reports": true,
    "sample": false,
    "interface": true,
    "tocVisibility": true,
    "access": true,
    "reportName": "North America Protein Market"
  },
```

Can anyone please help me

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with doing what you describe?  Parsing the JSON?  Creating the PPT?

Comment: Hi bill,am facing issue in parsing json to excel

Comment: This is the library typically recommended here: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON  Lots of posts here on that topic - https://www.google.com/search?q=jsonconverter.parsejson+site+stackoverflow.com

Comment: Got it  bill, but in the above we cannot able to generate PPT though JSON VBA

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting to find here, but typically this site is for helping you out with your own coding: it's unlikely anyone is going to write this for you.   If it's completely outside of your area of knowledge then maybe hire someone to do it.